# How to fix "Cannot connect: invalid settings" using phpMyAdmin on XAMPP (HY000/2054)

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, xampp, port

[image]

I changes port of MySQL 3306 to 3307 and creats a new user. But I can't access to phpMyAdmin.

Comment: I run on Windows 10 64bit

Answer (score 0):

### Change Port in XAMPP/mysql/bin/

As Apache port, we also can NOT change the MySQL port through the XAMPP Control Panel, to change it we have to edit MySQL configuration file.

To edit the configuration file, open my.ini file located in the XAMPP/mysql/bin/ directory, find words that contain number 3306, eq: port = 3306, then replace it with your own, such as 3307. and save it